# Kubectl create "invalid object"

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I am creating namespace using `kubectl` with `yaml`. The following is my `yaml` configuration

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
    name: "slackishapp"
    labels:
        name: "slackishapp"
```

But, when I run `kubectl create -f ./slackish-namespace-manifest.yaml`, I got an error like the following

```
error: SchemaError(io.k8s.api.autoscaling.v2beta2.PodsMetricStatus): invalid object doesn't have additional properties.
```

What goes wrong on my `yaml`? I am reading about it on the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/namespaces/#creating-a-new-namespace) as well. I don't see any difference with my configuration.

Answer (score 12):

There is nothing wrong with your yaml but I suspect you have the wrong version of kubectl.

kubectl needs to be within 1 minor from the cluster you are using as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#before-you-begin).

You can check your versions with

```
kubectl version
```

Comment: For updating 'kubectl.exe' on windows, replace it on "Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin" if you have docker desktop (see ibs4lif's answer below). Being pragmatic, before replacing i stopped 'Docker desktop', but i am not sure if that is required.

Answer (score 3):

Download the kubectl.exe on https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#before-you-begin then replace it on `Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin` if you have docker desktop

Like Andreas Wederbrand said, it is a version problem.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, try to create your namespace within imperative mode

```
kubectl create ns slackishapp && kubectl label ns slackishapp name=slackishapp
```

And then compare existing yaml with one you have written in order to check what is missing

```
kubectl get ns slackishapp -o yaml --export
```